# How do I declare an array of generic containers in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, typescript-generics

Consider our types,

```
type Types = 'a' | 'b'
```

and our container:

```
interface Container<T extends Types> {
    p: T,
    q: T,
}
```

Now here are two ways of declaring an array of these containers. My issue is that I have not clean a method of writing the first (good?) array without writing out all possible container types.

Some help would be greatly appreciated, or any insights into a better way of doing this all together :)

```
const goodArr: (Container<'a'> | Container<'b'>)[] = [
    {
        p: 'a',
        q: 'a',
    },
    {
        p: 'b',
        q: 'a', // compiler doesn't allow this
    },
];

const badArr: Container<Types>[] = [
    {
        p: 'a',
        q: 'a',
    },
    {
        p: 'b',
        q: 'a', // compiler allows this
    },
];
```

Comment: `p` and `q` should be equal, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use [`distributivity`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of conditional types.

It is easy to achieve. Just use `type Helper<T> = T extends any ? ...`

COnsider this example:

```js
type Types = 'a' | 'b'


interface Container<T extends Types> {
  p: T,
  q: T,
}

type Allowed<T extends Types> = T extends string ? Container<T> : never

const goodArr: Allowed<Types>[] = [
  {
    p: 'a',
    q: 'a',
  },
  {
    p: 'b',
    q: 'a', // compiler doesn't allow this
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oHICGaoB90CM0AoEgSwDtgIAnAMwwGNoBhAe0owpoB4YoIAHlXIATJHEgIAfFADeRKFDAAuWABoFUAI6qYGgL4lQkKAEEANudYB3CCN78hEUePjSUsR8LFQEwahQA5lAA-FBsHFzUvDKq5BAAbjQkDOx%20UIGsrCKm1NSqFla29hKIUgDaALoe5Zryiooq6FgaDdqqmGitUPrd9Q1NaITdijrNXVAA9JNQqQC2YKTmNFAirIjkaMBQGJY2UMAAFqQImr1ElQDcREA)